# How to get multivariate credible interval estimate(s) / highest density regions (HDR) after MCMC

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, credible-interval, highest-density-region

I'm estimating 15 parameters of my model using a Bayesian approach and a Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) method. My data after running a MCMC chain of 100000 samples is therefore a 100000×15 table of parameter values.

**I want to find 15-dimensional Highest Density Regions of my posterior distribution.**

**My problem:** Clustering the samples to assign them to HDRs (example using density-based clustering below) needs a distance matrix of all the samples. For 100000 samples, this matrix would take 37 GiB of RAM, which I do not have, not speaking of the computing time. How can I find my HDRs using reasonable amounts of computing resources? Someone *must* have had this problem before?!

**Edited to add:** According to [this SO question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102637/clustering-without-a-distance-matrix) and DBSCAN Wikipedia page, DBSCAN can be brought down to $\mathcal O(n\log n)$ time complexity and $\mathcal O(n)$ space complexity using a [spatial index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index) and avoiding a distance matrix. Still looking for an implementation or a description thereof...

---

### Multivariate highest density regions using density-based clustering (DBSCAN)

A X% highest density region is the region of a distribution which encompasses X% of the probability mass. As samples drawn by a MCMC method apprear with a frequency (asymptotically) proportional to the searched-for posterior distribution, my X% HDR also encompasses X% of my samples.

I planned to use the density-based clustering algorithm [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) to cluster my samples because density of samples is directly related to peak height of my posterior.

In analogy by the method of Hyndman (1996) ([paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2684423), [SO question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148439/what-is-a-highest-density-region-hdr)), I planned to increase the maximum distance a single sample may have from a cluster to be regarded a part of it iteratively until X% of my samples are part of some cluster:

[image: DBSCAN applied to MCMC samples]

After that step, I would calculate the range of each cluster in each dimension as a way to present my Highest Density regions.

In this example, you would be able to see that the 80% HDR encloses two distinct regions while the 50% HDR only contains one cluster. I would be able to visualize this like shown below, because the plot above is not applicable to more than 2 dimensions:

[image: HDR ranges visualized]

Comment: When you run an MCMC you observe the value of the target at each iteration (up to the same normalising constant), hence you can identify high density simulations in a much more precise way than by frequencies. You can also identify HPD regions by running a standard clustering algorithm on simulations with the highest posterior density values.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, @Xi'an. But can you specify what you think is a "standard clustering algorithm"? 
What algo could you suggest other than DBSCAN (or {single|complete}-linkage clustering, which is the same idea) if my notions of clusters are "points of high density"? Moreover, the most samples are in the regions of highest density, therefore If I want to calculate, say, the 90% HDI, I can only expect to exclude about  10% of my samples.

Comment: [Samworth & Wand (2010, *Annals of Statistics*)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1269452654) may offer an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a [Matlab Wrapper for ANN](https://github.com/jefferislab/MatlabSupport/tree/master/ann_wrapper). ANN is a library for approximate nearest neighbor searches ([homepage](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/implement/ANN/implement.shtml)). Besides the usual parameters of a spatial index region query, it uses an additional error parameter `eps` which gives the "approximateness" of the search: A returned nearest neighbor will be at most `1+eps` times farther from the query point than the true (non-approximate) nearest neighbor. Search for the term "error bound" in the [Programmers Manual](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/Files/1.1.2/ANNmanual_1.1.pdf) to find information about `eps`.

This enables me to include a fast nearest neighbor search in my DBSCAN implementation, which speeds up the process outlined in my question to a feasable duration. I will provide a link once the implementation is complete.